# I am getting this error "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'."

Tags: android, ios, sdk

**Error**

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

**What went wrong:**

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>    Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

**Try:**

1. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
2. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Get more help at [gradle.org](https://help.gradle.org)

> BUILD FAILED in 54s79 actionable tasks: 79 executed

Here is my **build.gradle**. Any help?

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tclm.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs "auto"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "01bab543-cce8-4e36-a755-6bc23fd66b7c",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:2.6.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-commons:2.6.3@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:2.6.3@aar'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.fnp:material-preferences:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.7.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // Required only if Facebook login support is required
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')

    // Required only if Twitter login support is required
    compile("com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0@aar") { transitive = true }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try to enable offline work from file>settings>build executions>gradle .try again

Comment: It's because of compile error in your java code try gradlew assembleDebug --info and fix compile error